# Find specific element position in XPath after checking a condition

Tags: html, xpath, xpathquery

I have the following html I am working with: (a chunk of it here)

```
<table class="detailTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="detailTitle" align="top">
        <h3>Credit Limit:</h3>
        <h3>Current Balance:</h3>
        <h3>Pending Balance:</h3>
        <h3>Available Credit:</h3>
      </td>
      <td align="top">
        <p>$677.77</p>
        <p>$7.77</p>
        <p>$7.77</p>
        <p>$677.77</p>
      </td>
      <td class="detailTitle">
        <h3>Last Statement Date:</h3>
        <h4>Payment Address</h4>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>   05/19/2015  </p>
        <p class="attribution">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to first check if "`Statement Date`" exists, and then find its position. Then get it's value which is in a corresponding `<p>` tag. I need to do this using XPath. Any suggestions?

So far I tried using `//table[@class='detailTable'][1]//td[2]//p[position(td[contains(.,'Statement Date')])]` but it doesn't work.

Comment: You realize it is not in the html you have shown?

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake @PadraicCunningham.. corrected

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I'm using xpath in Java code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is one possible way :** (formatted for readability)

```
//table[@class='detailTable']
//tr
/td[*[contains(.,'Statement Date')]]
/following-sibling::td[1]
/*[position() 
      = 
    count(
        parent::td
        /preceding-sibling::td[1]
        /*[contains(.,'Statement Date')]/preceding-sibling::*
    )+1
  ]
```

**explanation :**

- **`..../td[*[contains(.,'Statement Date')]]`** : From the beginning up to this part, the XPath will find `td` element where, at least, one of its children contains text `"Statement Date"`
- **`/following-sibling::td[1]`** : from previously matched `td`, navigate to the nearest following sibling `td` ...
- **`/*[position() = count(parent::td/preceding-sibling::td[1]/*[contains(.,'Statement Date')]/preceding-sibling::*)+1]`** : ...and return child element at position equals to *position of element that contains text `"Statement Date"`* in the previous `td`. Notice that we use `count(preceding-sibling::*)+1` to get position index of the element containing text `"Statement Date"` here.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

`//table[@class='detailTable'][1]//td[@class="detailTitle" and contains(./h3, 'Statement Date')]/following-sibling::td[1]/p[1]/text()`

This will find the `<td>` that contains the `Statement Date` heading, and get the `<td>` immediately after it. Then it gets the text content of the first `p` in that `<td>`.